# karaf (4.0.8) with commons-daemon

Tags: java, apache-karaf, procrun, apache-commons-daemon, prunsrv

We are using Karaf(4.0.8) for first time , we are almost completed all the stuff but stuck at service mode. We dont want to use service wrapper (which is tanuki license ). We want to use Commons-daemon.

I am trying to run Karaf with commons-dameon.

Any help / references  is greatly appreciated..  any steps on how to use common-daemon with Karaf

Thanks, 
Slok

Answer (score 0):

How to run Karaf as Service with Apache Commons Daemon ?

#### How do I get set up?

YOu Can change All Your Service Names in Install-Karaf-Service.bat.
If you want to change exe name then change in all batch files.

#### How to run with Latest Karaf

Download Fresh Karaf Zip from Karaf Site.
Copy All exe and bat files into Karaf Root folder.

Now go to Command prompt
karaf-4.0.8>Install-Karaf-Service.bat

Now you can verify in Windows Service with name "Karaf Daemon Service"

For Uninstalling Service ::::
karaf-4.0.8>Uninstall-Karaf-Service.bat
Deleted KARAF Successfully
Press any key to continue . . .

#### Which Architecture it Supports

Currently Exe I provided are amd64 because mine is 64-bit Machine. You can download 32-bit from Apache Commons Daemon Website .

[Repository Details](http://javaresolutions.blogspot.sg/2017/03/how-to-run-karaf-as-apache-commons.html)